# How to pass JAVA_HOME to Tomcat via WSO2

Tags: tomcat, wso2, java-home

I have WSO2 Apps Server running as a Service on Windows 7.
JAVA_HOME is set to
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`
I can access the admin screens at `https://localhost:9443` and that's all running sweet

I've uncommented the line in wrapper.conf and reinstalled the service and restarted it

```
#Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=bin/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=repository/conf
wrapper.java.classpath.9=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar
```

when i try to use the /example web application JSP scripts

```
/example/jsp/jsp2/el/basic-comparisons.jsp
```

I get an error from Tomcat

```
Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre"
```

I can copy the tools.jar into jre\lib\ext and get it to work but that feels like a bodge.
Where/Why is the jre bit being added to the JAVA_HOME and shouldn't the wrapper be passing the correct path to tools.jar to Tomcat?

Comment: Which Tomcat version are you running?

Comment: The one that's built in to WSO2 I assume - Apache Tomcat/7.0.14, I haven't installed a separate Tomcat server to my knowledge. Unless there's one built into the JDK7 that's getting in the way?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't having a problem passing `JAVA_HOME` into Tomcat -- it's definitely set. It's just not set to something that some component likes. Tomcat itself does not require a JDK (merely a JRE) so it's not the standard Tomcat that is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with set JAVA_HOME in some scrip that running WSO2AS. If you set JAVA_HOME to jdk correctly, so probably it's rewrite in script of starup your service. You need to check folder "bin" of WSO2AS to find script that set JAVA_HOME too.